# How to slice array in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor T of size [None, 4], and I want to slice it along the second dimension to give me a size [None] tensor. In numpy this would be T[:, DIMENSION], is there a fast way to do it with tensorflow commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same operation as numpy.

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[7,8,9,0]])
a.shape
```

the shape of `a` is 
`Out[]:TensorShape([Dimension(3), Dimension(4)])`

using the slicing operation, get values in the second dimension:

```
a[:, 2].eval()
```

and the output is

```
array([3, 7, 9])
```

Comment: Im using an old version of tensorflow and have to due to platform constraints. Any functions that do an equivalent thing?

Comment: can you list your tf version and some environment settings?